# Rate of growth of an RNA or DNA sequence

Tags: biochemistry

Given, e.g., a mixture of the necessary components in optimal conditions, what would be the average rate of attachment of nuceotides to ribose molecules?  This is related to the study of how long it would be expected take for a particular genome to evolve.

Comment: Your question is too vague and unclear. What exactly are the "necessary components"? Are there polymerases involved? Is there a template sequence? If you just take some RNA and mix it with ribonucleotides, exactly nothing is going to happen unless you have some sort of catalyst present, like an enzyme or ribozyme. The same is true of DNA. It takes energy to attach both nucleotides to ribose, and to attach (deoxy)ribonucleotides to each other. Please [edit] your question and clarify exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Also, this has nothing to do with how genomes evolve.